# How to delete all files in subfolder by time and size

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to ask for help in Linux. I have a main folder where are three subfolders with files.

I need to delete all files in the subfolders where the subfolder meet the conditions... the subfolder size is smaller than 5kb and the files in this subfolder are older than 5 minutes.

I did this, but I found it completely wrong.

```
find ./main/* -type 'f' -mmin +5 -size -5k -delete
```

Structure:
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buLn2.png)

Folder: Main -> Subfolders: first(2 files), second(2 files), third(2 files) see picture

And I would like to make an exception for the subfolder - "second". I mean these rules will not work on the "second" subfolder.

So I did this.

```
find ./main/* -type 'd' -size -5k -not -path "./main/second"
```

But I don't know how to implement the part where I use the condition for files(older than 5 minutes) and then these files will be deleted.

Thank you for any help.

I tried this code.
But it's always else

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
d="./main/*"
f="./main/*"
z=0

if [ "$d" == TRUE ] && ["$f" == TRUE ]
then
    $z="find $d -type 'd' -size -5k $f -type 'f' -mmin +5 -delete"
    echo "$z"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

and it is always else... :/

summarize:
I need to create a bash script that checks all the subfolders in the main folder.
And if it finds that a subfolder is less than 5kb in size. So the script checks the files in that subfolder to see if the files are older than 5 minutes and if all these conditions are met. This will delete all files from that subfolder.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: I tried... but still else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to delete all files in the subfolders where the subfolder meet the conditions... the subfolder size is smaller than 5kb and the files in this subfolder are older than 5 minutes.

`find -size` will not work on folders (at least not in the way you expect it to). You will have to use something like `du` for this.

Here is a script that should do what you want to achieve:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# The main directory
maindir="./main"

# Get list of subdirs in maindir
readarray -t subdirs < <(find "${maindir}" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -path "${maindir}/second" | sort)

# Process list of subdirs
for subdir in "${subdirs[@]}"; do

    # Determine size of subdir
    size=$(du -bs "${subdir}" | awk '{ print $1 }')

    # Skip subdirs that exceed 5k
    if (( ${size} > 5 * 1024 )); then
        echo "Skipping subdir '${subdir}' (size: ${size} bytes)"
        continue
    fi

    # Find and delete files in subdir older than 5 min
    echo "Deleting files in subdir '${subdir}'..."
    find "${subdir}" -type f -mmin +5 -delete

done
```

---

**Previous answer before OP provided more details - leaving this as is for future reference:**

---

Regarding your `find` command:

> I need to delete all files in the subfolders where the subfolder meet the conditions... the subfolder size is smaller than 5kb and the files in this subfolder are older than 5 minutes.

This would be:

```
find ./main -type f -size -5k -mmin +5 -not -path "./main/second/*" -delete
```

Explanation:

- You want to delete files, thus you need to find files using `-type f`
- `-path` needs a wildcard to function properly

---

Regarding your script code:

- `[ "$d" == TRUE ]` does a string comparison. You set `d="./main/*"`, so you test for `[ "./main/*" == "TRUE" ]`, which is never true as those are different strings (same for `$f`)
- If you want to actually run the find command, you need to do it like this: `$z=$("find $d -type 'd' -size -5k $f -type 'f' -mmin +5 -delete")`, but `$z` will be empty after this, as find does not print anything when `-delete` is used

If you want further advice, you need to provide more information about what your intentions are with the script - currently, this is not very clear (at least to me).

Comment: I have tried this option, but I don't think it's a correct command.. because first of all I need it to check the subfolders(all the content in a certain subfolder is smaller than 5kb) if yes... It should check the content(files) if it is older than 5 minutes.                                                           Can i use something like?    find ./main -type d -size -5k && -type f -mmin +1 -not -path "./main/second/*"  ... I know.. what i wrote is wrong... but something like that..

Comment: @Scholar: in that case, `find -size` won't help, as folders themselves have no size (from a filesystem perspective). I'll add something to my answer that might help you.

Comment: I know but these subfolders have some files and these files make the size of the folder.

Comment: @Scholar: check the edit I made, this should do what you want. I disabled the `-delete` part, only enable it once you made sure everything works as expected.

Comment: @Scholar: did you try the script I provided?

Comment: Where did you disable -delete part pls?

Comment: @Scholar: to enable deletion, remove the `#` from `#find "${subdir}" -type f -mmin +5 -delete` and delete line `find "${subdir}" -type f -mmin +5`.

Comment: I got it.. Thank you very much... May I ask if you have aby good online material for learning bash script? I would like to know what  many things mean in your code. Thank you

Comment: @Scholar: great, I'm glad I could help. I recommend to just experiment (but better not with deletion, could mess up your data if you make mistakes!). Bash is quite simple to learn. `man bash` gives a lot of good advice, and you should visit this page: https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/. Please mark my answer as accepted.